# pywhatkit, playonyt not opening requested video properly

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a code that will open the first video on YouTube when requested. Every time I try running my code it sends me to this URL: https://www.youtube.com%3E%3C/form%3E%3Ca%20href=, which doesn't work. I'ts a very basic code, but it should work and I'm very confused on why it doesn't. I've searched around the internet but didn't find any suitable answers to solve my problem.

```
import pywhatkit as kit

kit.playonyt("blinding lights")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a know bug in PyWhatKit, we are finding a solution for this, it seems this function is not working on a few machines, please check this https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/issues/45#issuecomment-818859387 for temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting "use api" to True.

```
kit.playonyt(song, use_api=True)
```

This solution is suggested here: https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/